# Leveraging dynamic imports adds `.at()` to the code, error as a result

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, es6-modules, polyfills

Here is my `.tsconfig` file:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "sourceRoot": "/"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

When I use dynamic imports, method `.at()` is added to the resulting code. Therefore, browsers, that doesn't support this method, throw an error `u.split(...).at is not a function`. Is there a way to fix this by tweaking `.tsconfig` file?

Comment: You're using [`noEmit: true`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noEmit), so no, tweaking `.tsconfig` will not change the code that is output. You'll need to change the configuration of the tool that you actually use for compiling/bundling/etc.

Comment: @Bergi can you tell me how can I fix the problem?

Comment: No, I can't, since you haven't shown us the tool (and its configuration) that is emitting the broken code.

Comment: yep, sorry. I use plain create-react-app with no direct access to webpack config

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it was not about leveraging dynamic imports itself. An external module hasn't been transpiled to ES6, and somehow this problem appeared only after dividing code into smaller chunks. Problem solved by downgrading that external module.

How the application worked just fine without code splitting remains a mystery.